# Bufferedreader and files encoded through ASCII

Tags: java, file, ascii, bufferedreader

I've got to read a file (it contains text) encoded through ASCII. I decided to use Bufferedreader class. I know that, when I deal with files encoded through UTF-8, I can specify the encoding using Bufferedreader. 
When I deal with ASCII files have I to specify the encoding type?

Thanks

Alessio

Comment: I think there is no need. Common text files notepad creates are ascii only.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should specify an encoding using `InputStreamReader` - `BufferedReader` doesn't let you specify the encoding.

For ASCII files you're *likely* to be okay with the platform default encoding (most defaults are compatible with ASCII), but personally I think it's best practice to always explicitly specify the encoding - it makes it clear what your intentions are, and that you really thought about it.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet! Sorry, but I don't specify the construction of the Bufferedreader object through InpuStreamReader and FileInputStream, but I was thinking as you wrote. So your suggestion is to specify the encoding. Thanks.

Comment: @AlessioG: Yes, basically - whenever you're converting binary data to text (or vice versa), be explicit how you're doing it.